# glassfish adapter missing in eclipse kepler

Tags: glassfish-4, java-ee-7, eclipse-kepler

hi Guys currently started to build my new workspace into a newly formatted PC,
all goes well until when I about to attached the server into my eclipse, the glassfish adpater is gone, below is a sample screenshotenter image description here.

can anyone help me how can I add the glassfish from here? thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

after days, weeks and so on. my problem is based on the java that is currently usin. JUNO  eclipse should be based on java 8 onwards, I cannot add the glassfish adapter due to the compatibility of java,eclipse and glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

I could install it manually adding the update site in *Install new software* menue instead the marketplace. Also needed JDK 8 for glassfish compatibility.